# Why can't I TTL serial log to my computer or connect to WiFi with my Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, serial-console

I haven't used my zero in about a year and I am trying to connect it to my new WiFi with no real success.
I tried:

-Editing the wpa_supplicant.config file and adding a shh file but when I check the network I show no new devices connected

-Reinstalling Raspbian Buster Lite

-Connecting the pi to a TTL Serial Cable but no devices show up when I run  `ls /dev/cu.*` I added `enable_uart=1` at the end of the config file and installed two drivers for console output on Macs to no avail

I am trying all this on a mac and am using a Raspberry Pi Zero W v1.1.  Does anyone know why I wouldn't be able to connect to WiFi or even serial log to my Mac?

Thanks!

Update: Here is the code to my wpa_supplicant.conf file

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="user"
    psk="pass"
}
```

Comment: `wpa_supplicant.config` it should be called `wpa_supplicant.conf` ... `adding a shh file` - that should be called `ssh` - and both of these files should be put in the boot partition (the first partition) ... `ssh` just an empty file, and the `wpa_supplicant.conf` needs to be correct - show what you've put in that file

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the original post

Comment: You missed using key_mgmt=WPA-PSK on your wpa_supplicant.conf. I followed this guide when setting up my Pi https://styxit.com/2017/03/14/headless-raspberry-setup.html.

Comment: By 'serial log' do you mean log in via a USB->Serial adapter? How are you trying to do this? Does logging in with a keyboard and a monitor connected to the HDMI port work?